# What will be the wait time before big query executes a query?

Tags: google-api, google-bigquery

Every time I execute a query in Google bigquery in the Explanation tab, I can see that their involves an average waiting time. Is it possible to know the percentage or seconds of wait time?

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to reduce the big query execution wait time to the minimum ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since BigQuery is a managed service, around the glob a lot of customers are using it. It has an internal scheduling system based on the billingTier (explained here https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#high-compute) and other internals of your project. Based on this the query is scheduled to be executed based on the cluster availability. So there will be a minimum time until it finds a cluster of machines to execute your job.

I never seen there significant times. In case you have this issue then contact google support to see your project. If you edit your original question and add a job ID, a google enginner may check it out if there is an issue orn ot.

Answer (score 0):

It's currently not exposed in the UI.
But you can find a similar concept from API (search "wait" from following page):
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#resource

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to reduce the big query execution wait time to the minimum?

Purchase more BigQuery Slots.

Contact your sales representative or [support](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/support) for more information.