# Why Big Query always has waiting time, is it possible to execute without waiting time?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

Whenever I execute a query in Bigquery, I can see that in the Explanation tab the Waiting time is always average. Is it possible to execute without wait time or to reduce the wait time.

[This image shows the query explanation (Bigquery wait time is average here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1SBu.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What will be the wait time before big query executes a query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39450162/what-will-be-the-wait-time-before-big-query-executes-a-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why Big Query always has waiting time?

You might have more work than can be immediately scheduled.

> is it possible to execute without waiting time?

Purchase more BigQuery Slots. 
Contact your sales representative for more information or [support](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/support).

Otherwise, just wait. If your job isn’t time-critical, you can schedule it and wait for it to be executed as resources permit.

Answer (score 0):

Bigquery has a complex scheduling system. Besides, usually there are couple stages for a simple query, and for each stage scheduler needs to find the best shard(node) which could execute the computation.
It takes some time for the scheduler to send the job to shards. But usually it should not be significantly long.